# Recharts: how to draw line animation from left to right?

Tags: reactjs, html5-canvas, recharts

I'm working with `Recharts` and would like the lines in [these graphs](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-glitter-excnv?file=/src/App.js) to draw from left to right. How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could simply reverse the order of your dataChart elements; since Recharts pays attention to the elements' place in the array when displaying the graphs.

So that in the end, you just need to call `chartData.reverse()` just before rendering your charts; just like this:

```
chartData.reverse();

return (
  <div className="App">
    <LineChart data={chartData}
      [...]
    />
  </div>
)
```